# Is it OK to call render method at the top?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, webhooks

My web app process webhooks from third-party API and I need to respond with 200 OK code when I receive them. Before doing actual processing in `some_api_webhook` method I need to check a few conditions and if any of them fails - I must not process further. Is it OK to call `render` method at the top of `some_api_webhook` method? Somebody told me that `render` should be placed only at the bottom of methods...

My original method:

```
def some_api_webhook
  unless condition_a
    render nothing: true, status: :ok, content_type: "text/html"
    return
  end

  unless condition_b
    render nothing: true, status: :ok, content_type: "text/html"
    return
  end

  unless condition_c
    render nothing: true, status: :ok, content_type: "text/html"
    return
  end

 # main logic is below  
 # ...
 # ...

end
```

Rewritten version which I prefer more because it does not have duplicating calls to `render`:

```
def some_api_webhook
  render nothing: true, status: :ok, content_type: "text/html"
  return unless condition_a
  return unless condition_b
  return unless condition_c

 # main logic is below  
 # ...
 # ...

end
```

Comment: could call it wherever you'd like

Comment: Why would you want to place render at the top?

Comment: osman, because if I place it at the bottom then it won't get called if some of the `return` statements above will be triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting I always assumed render would return from the action and anything below it wouldn't be processed. Just did a quick test and it turns out this is wrong. In the below code the put statement is still executed.

```
def index      
  render 'index'
  puts "Got here!"
end
```

So in that regard it doesn't matter where you place render unless the render was conditional which in your case it doesn't seem to be.